# UI-Grid v3.1.1 dropdownEditor filter binding

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to create a custom dropdown editor in UI-Grid.  I've followed Brian Hahn's blog post on this.

[This one](http://brianhann.com/ui-grid-and-dropdowns/)

I've got it mostly working except that I can't figure out the binding for the cellFilter that is defined in gridOptions, I'd like to take the one specifically in each column's colDef.

E.g. of code:

```
<ui-select-wrap>
    <ui-select ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" ng-disabled="disabled" append-to-body="true" autofocus="true">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Choose...">{{ MODEL_COL_FIELD | filter: col.cellFilter}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices
                repeat="item[editDropdownIdLabel] as item in editDropdownOptionsArray | filter: $select.search">
            <span>{{ item[editDropdownValueLabel] }}</span>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</ui-select-wrap>
```

For some reason its not calling the filter when I try to call it from the col.cellFilter. I'm hoping like MODEL_COL_FIELD there is some binding I can reference, but I can't seem to find it.

EDIT: added my grid options.

```
vm.gridOptions = {
    showGridFooter: true,
    rowHeight: 40,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true
};

vm.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    {name: 'id', enableCellEdit: false},
    {name: 'name', displayName: 'Name (editable)'},
    {name: 'age', displayName: 'Age', type: 'number'},
    {
        name: 'list',
        displayName: 'List',
        editableCellTemplate: 'app/index/templates/uiSelect.tpl.html',
        cellFilter: 'listFilter',
        enableCellEditOnFocus: true
    },
    {
        name: 'checkbox',
        displayName: 'Checkbox',
        type: 'boolean',
        cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD">'
    }
];
```

It doesn't seem like the cellFilter is getting applied in my custom dropdown.  I've tried using the CUSTOM_FILTERS as shown in the templates.

```
<ui-select-match placeholder="Choose...">{{ COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS }}</ui-select-match>
```

Even though I have cellFilters defined in the gridOption columnDefs when I check the CUSTOM_FILTERS variable, it comes back as undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of referencing the cell filter within the dropdown template, you can pass in the `cellFilter` to `gridOptions` like this -
From the example on Brian Hann's page

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    rowHeight: 38,
    columnDefs: [
      { name: 'name' },
      { name: 'age', type: 'number' },
      {
        name: 'gender',
        editableCellTemplate: 'uiSelect.html',
        editDropdownOptionsArray: [
          'male',
          'female',
          'other'
        ],
        cellFilter : 'customFilterName'
      }
    ]
  };
```